# Does AFNetworking Library work for IPv6? Or Does NSMutableURLRequest support IPv6?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

As according to apple developer doc to view Click [here](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/05/04/apple-says-all-apps-must-support-ipv6-only-networking-by-june)!
We can submit app on app store with using NSURLSession, NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection and CFNewtwork framework only. Can any one let me know that AFNewtworking library we can use for networking?